# Define editing date format in AG Grid

Tags: ag-grid, date-formatting

I have a SQL Server table which contains a `DATETIME` column `SaleDate` - and unfortunately, for now, I cannot change the datatype to just `DATE` (which would be sufficient).

I am trying to show data from that column in an Angular app using the Ag Grid.

For the display, I was able to use this in my Typescript code:

```
columnDefs = [
    ....
    { headerName: 'Sale', field: 'SaleDate', width: 120, editable: true,
      cellRenderer: (data) => {
          return data.value ? (new Date(data.value)).toLocaleDateString('de-CH', this.options) : '';
    },
    ....
]
```

and it works quite nicely.

However, when I try to edit this cell, unfortunately the whole `DATETIME` details (including the time portion) is being displayed:

```
[ 2018-09-27T08:43:59 ]
```

That'll be quite confusing to the users.... so is there a way to also somehow set / define the format for the editing in an AG-Grid cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have a workaround (prepare visual and real data) for `display` and `edit` things, you should create an own [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/) and [`cellEditor`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/) for this cell.

Or you can just create a `cellEditor` for calendar component and [`valueFormatter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-setters/) for displaying the date.

Just my case for same requirements `valueFormatter`:

```
let result: string;
if (params.value) {
    var formats = [
        moment.ISO_8601
    ];
    let date = moment(params.value, formats, true);

    if (date.isValid()) {
        let dateObject: Date = date.toDate();
        result = ('0' + dateObject.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.'
            + ('0' + (dateObject.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.'
            + dateObject.getFullYear();
        if (element.DataType == "datetime")
            result += ' ' + ('0' + dateObject.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':'
                + ('0' + dateObject.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':'
                + ('0' + dateObject.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    }
}
return result;
```

On custom `cellEditor` the major thing is `getValue` function - which will be used internally (for binding)

```
getValue(): any {
    let value =  (this.selectedDate.getFullYear() + '-' 
        + ('0' + (this.selectedDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' 
        + ('0' +  this.selectedDate.getDate()).slice(-2)
        +  'T'
        + ('0' + this.selectedDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':'
        + ('0' + this.selectedDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':'
        + ('0' + this.selectedDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2));
    return value;
}
```

And on the template, you can use any calendar template library.